# Удалить одинаковые соседние буквы из строки (js)

Tags: javascript, строки

Необходимо создать функцию, которая будет принимать строку и удалить повторяющиеся соседние буквы.
Например:

xxxYy == xxY 
xXxxyyy == xxyy

Как удалить все повторяющиеся - понятно. 
Но как удалить именно по одной соседней?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
console.log( bubu('xxxYy') ); // xxY
console.log( bubu('xXxxyyy') ) // xxyy

function bubu(str) {
  return str.replace(/(.)\1/gi, "$1");
}
```

`/(.)\1/gi` — `.` любой символ (кроме переноса строки), `\1` ссылка на то, что совпало внутри первых скобок (т.е. получается требование двойного совпадения чего-либо подряд). `i` — insensitive, игнорировать case. `$1` — уже в строке-замене, ссылка на совпадение внутри скобок.

---

`/(.)\1+/gi` а такое выражение (`+` одно или много совпадений подряд), будет удалять все соседние повторки.

Answer (score 1):

Можно предыдущую букву хранить в переменной и сравнивать с текущей, если равны, то текущую удаляем, а переменную, где хранилась предыдущая очищаем ( что бы удалять именно по одной )

```js
function test(string) {
  let prevChar = null;
  let result = '';
  for(let i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
    const currentChar = string[i].toLowerCase();
    if (prevChar === currentChar) {
      prevChar = null
    } else {
      result += currentChar;
      prevChar = currentChar;
    }
  }
  
  document.getElementById('result').innerText = result;
}
```

```html
<input id="input">
<button onclick="test(document.getElementById('input').value)">Test</button>
<br /><br />
Результат: <br />
<span id="result"><span>
```